# Eigenvectors of discrete Laplace matrix for 2D unit square under Neumann boundary condition

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, operator-theory, eigenfunctions

Eigenvectors of discrete Laplace matrix for 2D unit square with free boundary is simply
$$
\phi(x,y)= \cos(\frac{\pi}{n} kx) \cos(\frac{\pi}{m} ly) 
$$
It is easy to see that its 2nd order derivative equals itself (scaled).

For example, the Laplace matrix of a 4 by 4 grid is
[image]

The numerically computed eigenvectors are consistent with the expression $\cos(\frac{\pi}{n} kx) \cos(\frac{\pi}{m} ly)$.

My question is what is the following matrix:
[image]

Precisely put, **what is the differential equation** on a continuous 2D unit square domain corresponds to this discrete operator?

The value 4 corresponds to the inner nodes, value 3 for the boundary nodes, value 2 for the corner nodes. Is this the Laplacian under Neumann boundary condiction?

Second question: what are the eigenvectors of such matrix? Of course one can compute them numerically, but is there **an analytic expression for these  eigenvectors**? I find [this related entry](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/105264/non-standard-eigenfunction-plots-of-the-laplacian-over-the-unit-square) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/145192/comparing-analytical-solution-with-numerical-solution-of-helmholtz-equation-in-a) though they did not resolve my question.

Comment: It's still the Laplacian, but corrected for the nodes on the boundary. Or rather, a different numerical approach for the Laplacian.